# Select and insert multiple row values from a listview to a database

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2013, sqlite

I'm having a dilemma about my code, I want to select multiple values from a ListView, example table:

Number-|Name------|Surname
1---------|Travis------|Stever
2---------|Claudio----|Sanchez
3---------|Wes--------|Styles

Like so. I want my ListView to be able to select multiple rows, so in my example I'll select Travis and Wes only, and when I click a button I should be able to insert into a database the Number 1 and 3 only.

Any snippet would be leaps of help for me. Thank you in advance.

Here is my current code:

```
    Try
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            Dim StudentID = Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(0).Text)
            Dim FirstName = item.SubItems(1).Text
            Dim LastName = item.SubItems(2).Text
            DBConn()
            SQLSTR = "INSERT INTO '" & TextBox4.Text & "' (StudentID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('" & StudentID & "', '" & FirstName & "', '" & LastName & "') "
            alterDB()
            MsgBox("Students succesfully added", msgboxtitle)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    SQLCONN.Close()
```

But my current code only inserts the last clicked entry in my ListView. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, set ListView.MultiSelect to true.
This allows the user to select multiple items in the listview.

When the button is clicked, you can iterate through the selected items like so:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In listView.SelectedItems
    Dim number = Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(0).Text)
    Dim name = item.SubItems(1).Text
    Dim Surname = item.SubItems(2).Text

    'Add data to database
Next
```

LINQ approach:

```
Dim selectedEntries = From item In listView.SelectedItems
                      Select New With
                        {
                            .number = Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(0).Text),
                            .name = item.SubItems(1).Text,
                            .Surname = item.SubItems(2).Text
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Now, my question is how do I make my SQL statement? This is what I have in mind, is it correct? INSERT INTO Table (Number, Name) VALUES (number, name)?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way to insert data into your table.

Comment: Hi @Emile, every time that I press the button, the last clicked entry is the only one that gets inside the database. The code is written in the original post

Comment: I'm getting this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: @MicoRigunay Your selected listview item likely did not contain a valid integer; you could use `Integer.TryParse()` instead. Also consider getting the value from `item.Text`, rather than specifying the subitem explicitly.